# Ruby on rails input field css error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am using the devise gem in rails and i am using the grumby CSS framework,
The field for the 'email' input is over stretching the page and i am unable to fix it with a `width` or `size` attribute.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
display: inline-block
```

Comment: i have, thats not the issue, the alignment is fine, its the width of the email field over stretching the container, but the password field isn't also i am trying to this mostly inside of the ERB view itself and not have to make all these extra classes and varibles